# ModuleNotFoundError in Robotarium example code

Tags: python

I am trying to run example code on robotarium. However, I'm running into some issues. Here's the link to the code: https://github.com/robotarium/robotarium_python_simulator/blob/master/rps/examples/go_to_point.py

I got the error:

```
File "go_to_point.py", line 1, in <module>
    import rps.robotarium as robotarium
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rps'
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: did you install module `rps` using `pip` ? Or put folder `rps` in folder which you use to run your script `go_to_point.py`.

Comment: if you have module in folder `robotarium_python_simulator/rps` then you have to move `go_to_point.py` to `robotarium_python_simulator/go_to_point.py` and go to `robotarium_python_simulator/` and run it. This way it should find module `rps` withouth installing it.

Comment: @furas what do you mean by installing module rps using pip? I cloned the whole repo.

Comment: on [main page of this project](https://github.com/robotarium/robotarium_python_simulator) you have information about installation and line `sudo pip install .`

Comment: `go_to_point.py` doesn't know in which folder is `rps` but `import` as default searchs `rps` in folder which `pip` uses to install modules. If you install it with `pip` then `go_to_point.py` will find it.

Comment: other solution is to put `go_to_point.py` in folder `robotarium_python_simulator/` and run in this folder and it should find `rps` which is also in `robotarium_python_simulator/`

Comment: third solution is to apped full path `robotarium_python_simulator/` to `sys.path` before `import rps`. Command `import` uses folders from `sys.path` to search modules.

Comment: @furas thank you so much